# If string is found in line, replace with string from previous line, sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a few thousand lines of code spread out across multiple files that I need to update. Right now they are like so:

```
active_data(COPIED),
```

I need to replace all instances of COPIED (only in these lines) with the text inside the parenthesis on the previous line. So it total the code currently might look like:

```
current_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
active_data(COPIED),
```

and I want it to look like:

```
current_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
active_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
```

I can find the lines to be replaced easily enough, and could replace the with some static string with no problem, but I'm not sure how to pull the data from the previous line and use that. I'm sure its pretty simple but can't quite figure it out. Thanks for the help.

(I could see using AWK or something else for this too if sed won't work but I figure sed would be the best solution for a one time change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` could work but `awk` is more natural:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '$2 == "COPIED" {sub(/COPIED/, prev)} {prev=$2;} 1' file
current_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
active_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
```

- `-F'[()]'`

  Use open or claose parens as the field separator.
- `$2 == "COPIED" {sub("COPIED", prev)}`

  If the second field is `COPIED`, then replace it with `prev`.
- `prev=$2`

  Update `prev`.
- `1`

  This is cryptic shorthand which means print the line.  It is equivalent to `{print $0;}`.

#### How awk sees the fields

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "Line %s Field %s=%s\n",NR,i,$i;}' file
Line 1 Field 1=current_data
Line 1 Field 2=FOO|BAR|TEXT
Line 1 Field 3=,
Line 2 Field 1=active_data
Line 2 Field 2=COPIED
Line 2 Field 3=,
```

#### Changing in-place all files in a directory

```
for file in *
do
  awk -F'[()]' '$2 == "COPIED" {sub("COPIED", prev)} {prev=$2;} 1' "$file" >tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ "$file"
done
```

Or, if you have a modern GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace -F'[()]' '$2 == "COPIED" {sub("COPIED", prev)} {prev=$2;} 1' *
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how prev=$2 gets the data from the previous line, I'm sure I'm just missing something.

Comment: Everything before the first `(` is field 1.  Everything between the `(` and the `)` is field 2.  I updated the answer with code so that you can see how awk breaks up the fields.

Comment: It's probably fine but you should mention it'll fail if `prev` contains `&`. Also, the first arg for `sub()` is a regexp so for clarity at least you should use regexp delimiters (`/COPIED/`) not string delimiters (`"COPIED"`) since the latter force awk to convert the string to regexp before using it and make it look like `sub()` is operating on a string (in which case all chars would be literal) when it's not.

Comment: Ok this does seem to work (though I'm still a little confused on why, but I think I understand), but right now that command just prints out the new file effectively. What's the best way to have it update the old file? Also what would be the best way to run this on multiple files (or everything in a directory) and update all of them?

Comment: @JediWolf I added code to update all files in the directory in place.  (You tagged the question `linux`.  If your linux is reasonably up-to-date, then you can use the second slightly-simpler version that I included in the revised answer.)

Comment: That worked great, thanks. I know I have an up-to-date linux but it wasn't wanting to run the second one for some reason, but the first worked fine for changing all the files at once. Thanks again.

Comment: Very good.  It is no loss: the first version does the same as the second.  The second version requires [GNU awk version 4.1.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/QM51VPAlw4I) or newer.

Comment: You don't need the loop with the `-i inplace` version, just change `"$file"` to `*`.

Comment: @EdMorton Very good!  I see that that feature is documented in `man inplace`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\((\([^)]*\)).*\n.*(\)COPIED/\1\2/;P;D' file
```

This keeps a moving window of 2 lines open throughout the length of the file and uses pattern matching to effect the required result.

Comment: Clever.  I wasn't aware of `P`. +1

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[(][^)]*[)]|[^)(]*' -v OFS= '$2=="(COPIED)"{$2=prev} {prev=$2; print}' file
current_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
active_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk '
match($0,/\([^)]*\)/) {
    curr = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    if (curr == "(COPIED)") {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) prev substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    else {
        prev = curr
    }
}
{ print }
' file
current_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
active_data(FOO|BAR|TEXT),
```

Comment: Nice approach with the advantage that it avoids the complications of regexes: +1.